# Using "grep" command to find Crypto Seed Phrase

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cryptojs, cryptocurrency

Let’s say I have my 24 word crypto backup phrase somewhere on my PC and I don’t know where. it’s a total of 2048 words or so.
How can I use grep to print all/any files containing at least 2 words in given string? I found how to print with?
grep 'extra|value' but that’s for 2 words and they both must be found. how found I grep or whatever command to find any file containing at least 2 words from given string of 2048 words. thanks!

grep 'extra|value'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a single grep run to find two different words potentially on different lines. But you can first list all the files containing one word and then search only those for the second one:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l 'extra' {} + | xargs grep 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2 words and they both must be found

I would harness GNU `grep` for this task following way

```
grep --perl-regexp --recursive --null-data '(extra[.\n]*value)|(value[.\n]*extra)' .
```

Explanation: I start search from current directory (`.`) and traverse all subdirs (`--recursive`) looking for files which have (`extra` followed by zero-or-more any characters followed by `value`) OR (`value` followed by zero-or-more any characters followed by `extra`. I use `--perl-regexp` combined with `--null-data` combined with `\n` to allow words being in different lines. Consult [`grep` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) if you need further explanation of options used.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` + `awk`

```
find / -type f -exec awk 'FNR==1{a=b=0} /extra/{a=1} /value/{b=1} a&&b{print FILENAME; nextfile}' {} +`
```

That requires an awk that has `nextfile` which most do these days. If yours doesn't then pipe the output to `sort -u` or `uniq` to ensure unique file names.

Answer (score 1):

From `man grep` (GNU grep and BSD grep)

> -E, --extended-regexp
> Interpret PATTERNS as extended regular expressions (EREs,
> see below).
>
> ...
> grep understands three different versions of regular expression
> syntax: “basic” (BRE), “extended” (ERE) ...

That includes the use of logical "or" `|` in the search pattern.

- **-n**: print line numbers (somewhat guarantees `:` as record sep)
- **-o**: only print matches (more than one hit on same line)
- **-H**: print matching files names

The `awk` prints matched files with more than 1 hit.

```
% str="labore|dolor"

% grep -EnoH "${str}" {file,file2} | 
    awk -F ':' 'NF>1{x = $1} {mat[x,$NF]++} 
      END{for(i in mat){split(i, arr, SUBSEP); a[arr[1]]++}; 
          for(i in a){if(a[i] > 1){print i}}}'
file
```

include `-w` to only match whole words.

##### Data

```
% cat file
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
labore labore labore culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

% cat file2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```